# google cloud static hosting only shows html, but no website

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i want to host a single page on google cloud. only index.html. html is validated, but only the source code is shown under the link, no website.

inserted some other test html pages which work on google cloud (copied source code) but i get only html shown under Link.

what am i missing?

Comment: What exact product are you using? Compute Engine? Cloud Storage? Give more information about the specific product being used.

Comment: What product are you using? Where are you put the files?

Comment: i use cloud storage browser. the file (just one html page "index.html") is stored in a bucket. "Allusers" --> storage viewers. https://storage.googleapis.com/fronteris-makler-gmbh/Immobilienmakler-regensburg/index.html

Comment: @Elias can you check the `index.html` file type? From Cloud Storage Bucket click your index.html then look for the field Overview>Type.

Comment: @John  you mean edit object metadata? Its: text/html

Comment: Thanks @Elias, I tried your index.html content and there's no problem on my end. Please  try to re-create your file in your local machine then re-upload and browse again.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Your link, in fact, displays HTML, but the content of the HTML page is a HTML source.

When I open the link you provided - https://storage.googleapis.com/fronteris-makler-gmbh/Immobilienmakler-regensburg/index.html ` I see the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Immobilienmakler in regensburg - FRONTERIS MAKLER Gmbh</title>
<head>
```

But when I display the page source I see:

view-source:https://storage.googleapis.com/fronteris-makler-gmbh/Immobilienmakler-regensburg/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1671.5">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px 'Courier New'; color: #0000c2; background-color: #ffffff}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px 'Courier New'; color: #0000c2; -webkit-text-stroke: #0000c2; background-color: #ffffff}
    p.p3 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px 'Courier New'; color: #0000c2; -webkit-text-stroke: #0000c2; background-color: #ffffff; min-height: 17.0px}
    span.s1 {font-kerning: none}
    span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span class="s1">&lt;html&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span class="s1">&lt;head&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span class="s1">&lt;title&gt;Immobilienmakler in regensburg - FRONTERIS MAKLER Gmbh&lt;/title&gt;</span></p>
```

See the last line for example - it's your page title html encoded. I have no idea how you did achieve it, but you stored the html source as html file type and it was re-encoded as html. What kind of editor did you use? This would happen for example if you created your page in word and then stored it as .html type. Do you use some programming editor? At least Notepad++ or Atom, TextMate or whatever platform you do use.

Comment: "This would happen for example if you created your page in word and then stored it as .html type". So I did.....thanks for helping. problem solved.

Comment: Great to hear that.